# Single quote ( ' ) vs double quote ( " ) in SQL or SQL in Google Cloud

Tags: sql, backticks, quotation-marks

When I write SQL queries, I sometimes get error messages and am not sure if it's because I am not using a backtick, or single quote, or double-quotation marks. I just keep trying different quotation marks until it works. Sometimes it doesn't require any.

When are you supposed to use quotes and how do you know which ones to use?

Comment: In SQL, single quotes are for literals, and double quotes are for delimited identifiers.

Comment: Instead of just trying different things until something works, why don't you find a good tutorial or book and learn how things work? You'll never get far just flailing around on the keyboard. SO is not a tutorial site, and learning by asking one question after another here isn't a good way to learn and will take a lot longer than working through a tutorial.

Comment: I agree with you. I'm actually just barely halfway through the Google Data Analytics course so this is like my 4th day using SQL. It's fun but I'm still getting the hang of it.